# mock return value of other class method

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have following python code inside a function I call with my pytest:

```
#function.py

def get_object():
    object = manager.get_version(entity)
```

I want to mock this in my test but I don't know what to use as patch url. I know have:

```
@patch("functions.get_version")
def test_get_object(get_entities: MagicMock,):
#code with fixture
```

I don't know if this is even possible or the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

You must mock the object `manager` from **function**.

Example:

**manager.py**

```py
def get_version():
    return '0.0.1'
```

**functions.py**

```py
import manager

def get_object():
    object = manager.get_version()
    return object
```

**test_function.py**

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from functions import get_object

@patch("functions.manager")
def test_get_object(get_entities: MagicMock):
    get_entities.get_version.return_value = '1.0.0'
    assert get_object() == '1.0.0'
```

Comment: and what if manager is a parameter:
def get_object(manager):

Comment: The behavior would be the same in mock. You've set the `return_value`, so it will answer what you defined.

Comment: sorry but I got " filename does not have the attribute 'manager"

Comment: You need to debug more your code, because this isn't in the original question.